# get primary key of selected tableview row from realm db in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm developing an app using realm and swift. I've an **btrInfo** object.
I'm showing **btrInfo** as a uitableview. and in uitableview, "**hjemmelshaverr**" is displaying as row content. **btrInfo** object data is below:-

```
Results<btrInfo> (
[0] btrInfo {
    overskriftt = Test 1;
    hjemmelshaverr = Test 1 hi;
    id = 1;
},
[1] btrInfo {
    overskriftt = Test 2;
    hjemmelshaverr = Test 2;
    id = 2;
},
[2] btrInfo {
    overskriftt = Test 3;
    hjemmelshaverr = Test 3 haggard;
    id = 3;
}
)
```

now I'm not able to get **id** when one row will be selected. I can get **table row index but not id**. Here **id is the primary key**.

Searching it from 1 hour. but didn't get any proper answer. 
any help would be appreciated.

<<<  EDIT >>>>>>

self.table1Data contains below:-

### [Test 1 hi, Test 2, Test 3 haggard]

```
 func tableView(table1: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = table1.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel!.text = self.table1Data[indexPath.item] as? String

   // print(indexPath.item)
    //cell.contentView = table1Data[indexPath.item]


    return cell
}

 // add custom style
func tableView(table1: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?  {



        // 1
        let shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Edit" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

            print(indexPath.item)
        // 2
        let shareMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Do You  want to Edit", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        let twitterAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)

        shareMenu.addAction(twitterAction)
        shareMenu.addAction(cancelAction)


        self.presentViewController(shareMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)

            self.editReport(indexPath.item)
    })






    // 7

    shareAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    return [shareAction]
}
```

Comment: can you show your code of cellforrow

Comment: no no can you show the cellforrowAtIndexpath in your table row

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I just edited my question. plz check.

Comment: initially where you show the results in your view and where you want this,

Comment: I've created an editReport() function in my controller file. I want the id in this function.

Comment: ok where you already shown the result in viewcontroller

Comment: no I've created an segue and an new controller file has defined to it. I'm displaying the table view in this new view controller.

Comment: sister I am not in clear, can you show your cellforRowAtIndexpath Code

Comment: func tableView(table1: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = table1.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        
        cell.textLabel!.text = self.table1Data[indexPath.item] as? String
        
       // print(indexPath.item)
        //cell.contentView = table1Data[indexPath.item]
        
        
        return cell
    }

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik cellForRowAtIndexPath code given in chat and also edited my question

Comment: sory for delay can you show the self.table1Data

Comment: then problem not in here , ok we go on front , where you added the `self.table1Data`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121314/discussion-between-ripa-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like

**Step-1**

create one array of Dictionary like

```
var table1Data: [[String : AnyObject]] = ()
```

**step-2**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() { 
super.viewDidLoad() 

// Initiate realm 
let realm = try! Realm() 

 table1Data = realm.objects(btrInfo) 
}
```

**Step-3**

```
 func tableView(table1: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = table1.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    
    cell.textLabel!.text = self.table1Data[indexPath.item]["hjemmelshaverr"] as? String
            
    
    return cell
}
```

**step-4**

call like

```
    self.presentViewController(shareMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.editReport(self.table1Data[indexPath.item]["id"] as? String)
```